# Sencha ExtJs button - password Recovery email not working

Tags: javascript, extjs

This displays a confirmation message, but when I hit yes, it gives this error:
HTTP Status 415 -
description The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method.

```
 {
    xtype: 'button',
    id: 'passwordRecoveryButton',
    text: 'Reset Password',
    style: 'border-color: red',
    listeners: {
            click: function(button, event){
                var form = Ext.getCmp('gmiUserDetailsPanel').getForm();
                var currentRecord = form.getRecord();
                var emailId = currentRecord.get('emailId');

            Ext.Msg.show({
                title:'Password Recovery',
                msg: 'Are you sure you want to send a password recovery email to ' + emailId +'?',
                buttons: Ext.Msg.YESNO,
                icon: Ext.Msg.QUESTION,
                fn: function(btn) {
                    if (btn === 'yes') {
                        Ext.Ajax.request({
                            url: 'admin/passwordRecovery.htm',
                            jsonData : emailId,
                            method: 'POST',
                            success: function(response){
                                Ext.Msg.show({
                                msg: 'Email successfully sent to ' + emailId +'.',
                                })
                                },
                            failure: function(response){
                                Ext.Msg.show({
                                    modal  : true,
                                    title  : 'Unable to send email!',
                                    msg    : 'Unable to send email to :  '+emailId+', please contact support team.',
                                    icon   : Ext.Msg.ERROR,
                                    buttons: Ext.Msg.OK
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

},

        },
```

---

I am attempting to pass the information of the current record (or just the email) and this is in the java controller:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/passwordRecovery", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        @Secured("ADMIN")
        public
        @ResponseBody
        UserOperationResponse PasswordRecoveryEmail(Model model, HttpServletRequest request, @RequestBody UserOperationRequest userOperationRequest) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, MessagingException {
            UserOperationResponse userOperationResponse = new UserOperationResponse();
```

[...]

Comment: The stuff in the success function is invalid JS... the "msg: 'Email succ..." stuff should be wrapped in Ext.Msg.show I assume

Comment: So what is the question? You're sending something the server doesn't expect. What does the server expect?